# Noise coming from dunlop gcb95 original crybaby

Tags: maintenance, effects-pedal

I'm using a dunlop gcb95 original crybaby. It's powered by a zoom ad16 9v adapter. The problem is, there's no noise if I use any clean preset in my fender mustang II amp, but using metal 2000 or any high gain preset introduces an unbearable buzz even if the wah is turned off, and there're no other pedals in the chain. FYI, this pedal is not modded, hence no true bypass.

My question is, is this a common issue with gcb95, because I've used another psu also, and the noise was still there? Depending on the cause, I may have to buy a power supply or a new wah unit, as it's driving me crazy. I've checked my other pedals also, and I'm sure they are not causing this noise.

Comment: Checked with just a battery? [& as a complete aside, how does Dunlop get to claim it's an 'original' CryBaby? My CryBaby, late 60s/early 70s possibly, says "made in Italy by Jen" on the base.

Comment: Yup, same thing with battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original CryBabys hum.  It's usually quiet but as you've heard, certain effects can exacerbate the problem.  And there's no true bypass.  I suggest you get a different model of wah and test it in the store with your set up.  I personally use a 535Q Cry Baby Multi-Wah but YMMV.